# Terraform - Error creating NAT Gateway: InvalidElasticIpID.Malformed

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc, elastic-ip

I want to use Terraform to create a VPN with a fixed public IP address that I can assign to our Lambda functions.

I found this blog post and code that does this:

- Blog post: https://jaffarshaik.medium.com/implementing-vpc-architecture-using-terraform-3de6c42d7646
- Github: https://github.com/Jaffarterraform786/vpc

However, when I run the script I get this error:

```
│ Error: Error creating NAT Gateway: InvalidElasticIpID.Malformed: The elastic-ip ID 'aws_eip.ip.id' is malformed
│       status code: 400, request id: 96b26796-931d-4470-85b5-5c46c39889a9
│ 
│   with aws_nat_gateway.natgateway,
│   on natgateway.tf line 1, in resource "aws_nat_gateway" "natgateway":
│    1: resource "aws_nat_gateway" "natgateway" {
```

This is the content of the natgateway.tf file:

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "natgateway" {
  allocation_id = "aws_eip.ip.id"
  subnet_id     = "aws_subnet.publicsubnet.id"
  tags = {
    name = "prod nategatway"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_eip.eip]
}
```

Things I tried:

- Running scripts on a clean region with no other VPCs created - still didn't work
- Raised an issue on Github: https://github.com/Jaffarterraform786/vpc/issues/2
- Ran the Terraform checkers to see if there's any errors, none found.

Any clue or something in the scripts that I need to change?

Comment: What is your actual TF code that you run?

Comment: @Marcin I am running the code at https://github.com/Jaffarterraform786/vpc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are strings with mistakes in `natgateway.tf`. The corrected version is:

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "natgateway" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.eip.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.publicsubnet.id
  tags = {
    name = "prod nategatway"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_eip.eip]
}
```

Please note that I do not check the validity of the VPC or its other resources. I'm just addressing the error you've reported.

Comment: Hi @Marcin I would like to add a tip, if I may. I looked on the repo and it would be better to use the `Internet Gateway` resource on `depends_on` than the `EIP`. The `Internet Gateway` can fail due to so many reasons, but the EIP is something simple to create and can give a "false positive"  to `Nat Gateway ` terraform resource.